# two different webform pages share top content

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-webform

I have a drupal page with two seperate webform contents. Now if i want to add content on top of the actual form, it is mistakedly share across both pages, why is that and how can i keep the content seteprate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just recreated one of the Webform pages and this time things kept sepparately - weird...